# How to edit default binaries executed by which

Tags: debian, upgrade, openssl, libraries

Our server is running on an old version of Debian 7.10 (Wheezy) and we need to renew SSL certificates for a specific domain.

Our version of OpenSSL is super old, but it's the last one for our version of Debian.

```
~ apt-cache policy openssl          
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1t-1+deb8u12
  Candidate: 1.0.1t-1+deb8u12
```

It is quite buggy and `~ openssl version` return `openssl: symbol lookup error: openssl: undefined symbol: i2d_DHxparams` I found that is it because `i2d_DHxparams` is implemented in OpenSSL versions `1.0.2+`.

So I have to update OpenSSL. I followed carefuly this tutorial : https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/ with the last stable version I found `OpenSSL 1.1.1g`.

The new version is well installed and compiled in the folder `/usr/local/ssl/lib`.

It is impossible to point `~ which openssl` to the right folder, it always return `/usr/local/bin/openssl` which is the previous OpenSSL version. I tried to edit `/etc/environment` and `/etc/profile.d/openssl.sh` then sourced it in the PATH, but `which openssl` is still returning `/usr/local/bin/openssl` instead of `/usr/local/ssl/lib/openssl`.

If somone know how to edit this PATH to respond with the new version of OpenSSL, thank you !

Comment: In the tutorial they renamed the original binary which makes sense if `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/local/ssl/bin` in the PATH. Note that the PATH to the binary is `/usr/local/ssl/bin` and not `/usr/local/ssl/lib/openssl`.

Comment: Yes, I see this, but in the tutorial section "Configure OpenSSL Binary", the screenshot indicates `/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl` and not `/usr/local/ssl/bin/`. Is there a way to indicate to the server to use this new version compiled in `/usr/local/ssl/lib` ?

Comment: (1) If your binary is `/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl`, then you'll have to add `/usr/local/ssl/bin` to the PATH.
(2) Rename the original binaries.
(3) Add `/usr/local/ssl/lib` to a `*.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and run `ldconfig` as described in the tutorial.

Comment: Instead of investing time into patchwork you should be looking into an upgrade to Debian stable.

Comment: You might be trying to solve the wrong problem. The packaged version of `openssl` should still work: try `/usr/bin/openssl version` explicitly, to avoid the broken version in `/usr/local/bin`. The `apt-cache policy` output is surprising for a Debian 7 system, the `deb8` version suffix means that the Debian 8 repositories are included; what does `apt-cache policy` (with no package) produce?